# how do can I check whether a date is within business hours in f#?

Tags: f#

I m trying to write a simple function in fsharp to check the business hours but it aint working.

This is what I have:

```
let businessdate dts =
    let newdts = DateTime.FromOADate dts
    match newdts with
    | not DayOfWeek.Saturday & not DayOfWeek.Sunday & DateTime.Hour >= 8 & DateTime.Hour <= 20 -> 1
    | _ -> 0
```

This fails. Is it possible that DateTime in Fsharp does not have the member hour? How could I do this please?

Comment: error FS0010: Unexpected infix operator in pattern - this is for the >= sign in DateTime.Hour >=8

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The problem with your snippet is that you are using pattern matching in a bit odd way. You cannot quite put arbitrary code in the patterns of the `match` clause - you can use constants (like `DayOfWeek.Saturday`) to check whether a value is equal to something, or you can use variable assignment with `when` clause to check for condition:

```
let businessdate dts =
    let newdts = DateTime.FromOADate dts
    // Match on day of week and hour properties of the date time
    match newdts.DayOfWeek, newdts.Hour with
    // For weekend, return false
    | DayOfWeek.Saturday, _ | DayOfWeek.Sunday, _ -> false
    // For working hours, return true
    | _, h when h >= 8 && h <= 20 -> true
    // For non-working weekday hours, return false
    | _ -> false
```

You could make this a bit nicer by using active patterns, but that's a more advanced feature, so I'd recommend looking into that later, once you get familiar with basic patterns.

PS: In practice, this will probably not work, because of things like bank holidays, but I guess that's not the point of your question.

Comment: thanks Tomas. Well it works for what I need to do with it (Definition of Peak and OFfpeak contracts in power markets) but also I m still learning and trying to figure out when to use f# and when to use c# for my issues...